# Как сделать чтобы на мобильном срабатывал :hover если возить пальцем по экрану?

Tags: html, css, hover

Есть простой html.

```
<head>
<style>
  div.hdiv {width: 200px; height:200px; margin:5px; display:inline-block;}
  div.hdiv {background: red;}
  div.hdiv:hover {background: green;}
</style>
</head>
<!-- -------------------- -->
<body>
<div class="hdiv">Содержимое</div>
<div class="hdiv">Содержимое</div>
</body>
```

Хотелось бы чтобы на мобильных эффекты :hover срабатывали когда над элементами возишь пальцем по экрану. Пока они работают только в момент нажатия на экран.

Как такое сделать?

Comment: Возможно вам надо :active ?

Comment: возможно :focus еще как-то поможет